# Where is nodejs chaincode stored in a container? and is it compiled?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am learning hyperledger fabric and am curious where is the nodejs chaincode stored in a container after it has been installed and instantiated?

Also the docs say the chaincode is compiled - is that applicable to nodejs also? How is nodejs compiled? What compiler is used? Is the compilation output some VM bytecode or is it machine code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NodeJS chaincode can be found under `/usr/local/src` of the docker container in which its instantiated. It is not compiled into anything.

```
$ docker exec -it dev-peer1-jnj-mycc-1.0 /bin/bash
root@0dbcfb72e6d8:/# ls /usr/local/src
chaincode.js  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json
```